# MVC error: "Error" view gets returned rather than "Success" view, despite valid info being entered

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

The Error view is only supposed to get returned if one or more fields in the form is null or empty, but it gets returned even if correct information is entered.

I have a method in my Home Controller that takes string parameters, and has an "if" statement that checks if each field in the form is null or empty.  If null/empty, it's supposed to return the Error view that is stored in the shared folder.  If not, it returns "Success," (a view file which I added to my Home View folder).  However, the Success view is never hit, regardless of whether valid info is entered into the form.  It returns the Error Page either way.  I'm unsure if you can tell what the problem is from the code below, but here's my Index and Home Conntroller code.  If there's something else you'd need to see, please let me know.  Also, my apologies if this is not the right way to ask questions; I'm very new to MVC's and forums like this.

**Below is the Home Controller code:**

```
namespace InsuranceApp.Controllers
{
       public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Quote(string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, string DateofBirth, string carYear, string carMake, string carModel, string speedingTickets, string dui, string coverage)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(emailAddress) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(DateofBirth) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(carYear) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(carMake) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(carModel) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(speedingTickets) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(dui) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(coverage))

            {
                return View("~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml");
            }

            else
            {
                return View("Success");
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

INDEX CODE:

```
<div class="row no-gutters m-3">
    <div class="card col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-6 mx-auto shadow">
        <div class="card-header text-center">
            <h5 class="m-0">Auto Insurance Quote Generator</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Quote", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <input name="FirstName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <input name="LastName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <input name="EmailAddress" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <input name="DateOfBirth" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Date of Birth MM/dd/yyyy" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <input name="CarYear" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Car Year" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <input name="CarMake" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Car Make" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <input name="Car Model" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Car Model" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <input name="SpeedingTickets" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="How many speeding tickets do you have?" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <input name="DUI" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Have you ever had a dui?" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                        <input name="Coverage" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Would you like Full Coverage or Liability?" />
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have a space in `name="Car Model"` (look at the actual html it generates - you donot have a form control with `name="CarModel"` therefore `carModel` is `null`). Suggest you go to the MVC site and work through a few basic tutorials to learn the basics of how to create a view using the strong typed HtmlHelper` methods and get client and server side validation.

Comment: Thank you Stephen! You are right, I have fixed it.  I will go to the MVC site to view the tutorials, as  you suggested. Thanks!

Comment: Add `[Required]` attributes to your properties. And use `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.YourProperty) @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.YourProperty) and @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.YourProperty)` in the view and include the scripts for client side validation - refer [Adding Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-validation)

Comment: And you might want to consider removing your acceptance of that wrong answer so that other users are not misled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your names in the Controller are not the same as the names in the html file.

In MVC you need the exactly the same name with lower and upper case letters.

If the name in the HTML file is 'Name' in the controller needs to be 'string Name' not 'string name'.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I'm fixing it now and will update soon.  Much appreciated!

Comment: It worked perfectly!  A silly mistake on my part. Thank you  Krusto, for bringing it to my attention:)

Comment: I made that one too when I started several months ago. I hope now that you are not raging because of it. I was about to throw the computer from the 8th floor after checking for 5 hours for errors.

Comment: Wrong - the `DefaultModfelBinder` is not case sensitive